# C# string manipulation - How to remove the first element of each concatenated string in a collection

Tags: c#, string, listview

I am creating concatenated strings based on the data in each row of my ListView control. I need to figure out how to remove the first element in each string which pertains to a single row of the ListView. How might I accomplish this? This is a C# winforms project.

**Here is my current code:**

```
        foreach (ListViewItem HazPackErrItems in HazmatPackageErrorListview.Items)
        {
            string HazPackErrRow = " ";

            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem HazPackErrSub in HazPackErrItems.SubItems)
            {
                HazPackErrRow += " " + HazPackErrSub.Text + ",";
            }
            // Remove comma after last element of string.
            HazPackErrRow = HazPackErrRow.Substring(0, HazPackErrRow.Length - 2); 
            MessageBox.Show(HazPackErrRow); // List concatenated subitems
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't add it in the first place?

```
foreach (ListViewItem HazPackErrItems in HazmatPackageErrorListview.Items)
    {
        string HazPackErrRow = " ";

        bool first = true;
        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem HazPackErrSub in HazPackErrItems.SubItems)
        {
            if (first) 
                first = false;
            else
                HazPackErrRow += " " + HazPackErrSub.Text + ",";
        }
        // Remove comma after last element of string.
        HazPackErrRow = HazPackErrRow.Substring(0, HazPackErrRow.Length - 2); 
        MessageBox.Show(HazPackErrRow); // List concatenated subitems
    }
```

Comment: ... and then rewrite it to use a StringBuilder too :)

Comment: True, but that wasn't what he was asking. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is based on Inferis's answer, but it uses a StringBuilder and avoids the need for the final Substring call:

```
foreach (ListViewItem errors in HazmatPackageErrorListview.Items)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    bool first = true;
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem error in errors.SubItems)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (builder.Length > 0)
            {
                builder.Append(", ");
            }
            builder.Append(error.Text);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString()); // List concatenated subitems
}
```

Here's an alternative way of tackling the delimiter issue:

```
foreach (ListViewItem errors in HazmatPackageErrorListview.Items)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    bool first = true;
    string prefix = "";
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem error in errors.SubItems)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Append(prefix);
            prefix = ", ";
            builder.Append(error.Text);
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString()); // List concatenated subitems
}
```

Of course, there's a simpler way:

```
foreach (ListViewItem errors in HazmatPackageErrorListview.Items)
{
    string[] bits = errors.SubItems.Skip(1)
                          .Select(item => item.Text)
                          .ToArray();
    string errorLine = string.Join(", ", bits);
    MessageBox.Show(errorLine);
}
```

Comment: With this, the string begins with a comma.

Comment: I was in the middle of fixing that :)

Comment: Answer stealer!  ;P  I don't really like your solution to the issue I commented on earlier...  Seems kinda hackish.

Comment: I prefer that way to having to take it off the end earlier. There's an alternative way though... I'll edit.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I think that method's better (and acceptable by me, though I would break on first instead of a larger if).

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Linq, use String.Join(), it reads a lot easier:

```
    foreach (ListViewItem HazPackErrItems in HazmatPackageErrorListview.Items)
    {
        string HazPackErrRow = string.Join(", ", HazPackErrItems.SubItems.Skip(1).Select(s => s.Text).ToArray())

        MessageBox.Show(HazPackErrRow); // List concatenated subitems
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IList<T>.Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

```
foreach (var HazPackErrSub in HazPackErrItems.SubItems.Skip(1))
```

Because other people seem to be rewriting your code, why not I?  =]

```
foreach(ListViewItem HazPackErrItems in HazmatPackageErrorListview.Items)
{
    string HazPackErrRow = String.Join(", ", HazPackErrItems.SubItems.Skip(1).Select(t => t.Text).ToArray());

    MessageBox.Show(HazPackErrRow); // List concatenated subitems
}
```

Comment: You need to call ToArray - String.Join doesn't work with IEnumerable<string>.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you could just use a for loop and start the index at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

add the comma at the beginning, then you only have to do one check, rather than a check on every iteration

```
string HazPackErrRow = "";
foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem HazPackErrSub in HazPackErrItems.SubItems)        
{
            HazPackErrRow +=  "," + " " + HazPackErrSub.Text;        
}
// Remove comma before first element of string.
if(HazPackErrRow.Length > 0)
 HazPackErrRow = HazPackErrRow.Substring(1);
```

Edit:
Um, ignore me, I misread the question.